# Transaction inside stored procedure with input parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_Update_Quantity]
(
    @Quantity INT,
    @Product_ID INT
)
AS
BEGIN
begin try
Begin Transaction
    update Product
    Set Product.Quantity=(Product.Quantity-@Quantity)
    where (Product.Quantity-@Quantity>0)
    AND @Product_ID IN (Select Product_ID from Product)

    insert into Product_Sales(Product_ID,Quantity)
    values(@Product_ID,@Quantity)
commit Transaction
print 'Successfull Inserted'
end try
begin catch
    Rollback Transaction
    print 'Operation is not Successfull'
end catch
END
```

My stored procedure is working fine but the problem is it is not checking the

```
(quantity - @quantity) > 0
```

condition.

If my input quantity is greater than the quantity of a specific product data is only inserting into Product_Sales table.But i want if the condition `(quantity - @quantity) > 0` fails the transaction will rollback but it is committing the transaction. Why? How to solve the problem?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: There's nothing to raise an error in your procedure.  It will evaluate the where clause, find 0 rows that meet those conditions, update 0 rows, and continue.

Comment: I think you're not just updating the row with Product_ID = the parameter value (as you probably intended), but rather updating all rows with Quantity > @Quantity as long as the passed Product_ID parameter is in the table at all!!!  It looks like the answer by Muhammed Ali below fixes that.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[usp_Update_Quantity]  --<--- See explanation by marc_s in your comments 
(                                                 -- about using sp prefix for your procs
@Quantity INT,
@Product_ID INT
)
AS
BEGIN
begin try
           DECLARE @Stock INT;

           SELECT @Stock =  Product.Quantity 
           FROM Product 
           WHERE Product_ID =  @Product_ID

           IF (@Stock < @Quantity)
            BEGIN
             RAISERROR('Not Enough Stock', 16, 1)
             RETURN
            END

    Begin Transaction
            update Product
            Set Product.Quantity=(Product.Quantity-@Quantity)
            where Product_ID =  @Product_ID


            insert into Product_Sales(Product_ID,Quantity)
            values(@Product_ID,@Quantity)
    commit Transaction
        print 'Successfull Inserted'
end try

begin catch
  IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
      Rollback Transaction

     print 'Operation is not Successfull'
end catch
END
```